# Configure Namecheap mail with Zerigo DNS

Tags: dns, heroku, namecheap

I need to configure my DNS as follows:

[image]

I am using Heroku and Zerigo to manage DNS. However, Zerigo will not let me set the hostname to `@`.

Has anyone ever experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the hostname for each zone entry, **mail**.example.com, **www**.example.com etc

[What's the meaning of '@' in a DNS zone file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/83874/whats-the-meaning-of-in-a-dns-zone-file)